# Is there a .NET implementation of an XRI resolver?

Tags: .net, openid, xri

In order to avoid delegating XRI resolution to an XRI resolver proxy like xri.net, is there an open source .NET implementation of an XRI resolver?

There is an xri4j library that might be ported to .NET, and in fact I started on that effort, but it looked like there was a lot of code in there that could be ripped out since .NET's libraries have a lot of the functionality that (apparently) Java lacks.  But it's a lot of work to refactor it all.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [dot net openid project](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) relevant to you?

The svn change logs seem to indicate some level of XRI support.

Edit: This project is the intended target, it currently uses the external server!

Comment: LOL.  Thanks, Shuggy.  I actually work on the DotNetOpenId project myself, and although it has support for XRI, it pushes XRI resolving onto an external server.  I'm actually hoping to enhance DotNetOpenId with internal XRI resolution by finding a .NET library that does it -- thus the question.  
But thanks anyway. :)